# How to map properly a many-to-one relationship with @IdClass?

Tags: java, hibernate

I wanted to create a table in Hibernate with a composed Primary key. One part of the Primary key is an auto-generated value and the other part references the Primary key of another table in a many-to-one relationship.

I didn't use @EmbeddedId because I didn't manage to make work the auto-generation inside the @Embeddable class. So finally I decided to use the @IdClass.

After some Research I came up with the next code:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PartidaId.class)
@Table(name = "partida", schema="trueskill")
public class Partida implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 659832134987666699L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name ="partida_id")
    private Integer partida_id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "jugador_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer jugador_id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "jugador_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Jugador jugador;

    @Column(name = "PUNTOS")
    private int puntos;

    ....
}

public class PartidaId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 997366452999076354L;

    private Integer jugador_id; 
    private Integer partida_id;
    ...
}
```

It compiles correctly but when I try to persist one Entity:

```
Jugador p1 = new Jugador("Player1");
Partida part1 = new Partida(7, p1);
em.persist(p1);
em.persist(part1);
```

I receive the following error:

```
17:54:31,369 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] - insert into trueskill.partida (jugador_id, PUNTOS, partida_id) values (?, ?, ?)
17:54:31,374 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
17:54:31,374 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [7]
17:54:31,374 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [null]
17:54:31,374 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [4] as [INTEGER] - [4]
17:54:31,390 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - SQL Error: 20000, SQLState: XCL14
17:54:31,390 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - Die Spaltenposition '4' befindet sich außerhalb des Bereichs. Die Anzahl der Spalten für dieses ResultSet liegt bei '3'.
17:54:31,392 ERROR [org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl] - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [model.Partida]]
```

The problem is that it tries to insert one extra "null" parameter, when there should be only 3. Could someone tell me why is this happening?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the integer jugador_id in the partida entity. You probably have an @Id in the jugador entity maped in a @oneToMany relation with the partida class.

Delete from Partida:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "jugador_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer jugador_id;
```

Use this in Partida entity:

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "jugador_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Jugador jugador;
```

Make sure you have something like in your Jugador class.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "partida", referencedColumnName = "partida_id")
private Partida partida;
```

As I said in the answer, you must have this code in the entity Jugador :

```
@Id
@Column(name = "jugador_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer jugador_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried what you said:  

In the Partida class:  
`@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "jugador_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Jugador jugador;`

In the Jugador class:  
    `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "partida", referencedColumnName = "partida_id")
    private List<Partida> partidas;`

But now hibernate complains because:

`There is no primary key attribute to match the ID class attribute jugador_id`

Comment: You are welcome. The problem here is that in your Jugador class isnt the @Id
You only need to copy what i said:
**@Id**
 @Column(name = "jugador_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 private Integer jugador_id;